# How many threads should I use for processing 1,00,000 elements in a web crawling app?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have 1,00,00 elements to use in my web crawling app. I am confused to choose the number of threads to be used with Executor Service (Java 6).

Actually I am getting Out Of Memeory Error if I use more threads which makes me confused to choose the number of threads. Also as many threads hit the server, the internet gets halted and I have to restart my PC everytime.

Could someone help me choose the number of threads for this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to say, because the limiting factors in terms of throughput is probably **your system's** network bandwidth and latency.  If you try to go beyond that limit, you are likely to *reduce* throughput due to various secondary effects: e.g. congestion, thrashing, throttling (by the server), etc.

The correct approach is to make the number of threads in the pool a configuration parameter ... and tune it.  Start small, and when increasing the thread count doesn't improve throughput significantly, stop increasing it.

Comment: I meant that Executor Service is in Java 6. But I am working with jdk8 only. While trying with Fork/Join (Java 7) or Parallel Streams (Java 8), we can't specify the subtasks of this operation. But it can be done with Executor Service.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs Stephen!

Comment: In java8 you can specify the number of threads which will be created in the thread pull: fixed threadpool: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html

Comment: @StavAlfi - His comment implies that he already knows that.  That's why he chose ExecutorService not one of the other alternatives.  He is really asking about how large to make the pool.  And there is no simple answer to that.

Comment: @VijayPalaniappan - I'm pretty sure that neither Fork/Join or parallel Streams would be a good approach ... even if you *could* specify their pool sizes.